# Speed up posterize image function

Tags: image-processing

I have a list of colours that I would like to "posterize" an image into. I am using the following code, which converts the hues to points in an hsb colour space, then uses the replace rule:

```
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}] , 200];
cols = {{0.13, 0.45, 0.69}, {0.56, 0.54, 0.98}, {0.04, 0.9, 0.97}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};

id = ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "HSB"]];
dat1 = Flatten[({#2 Cos[2 Pi #], #2 Sin[2 Pi #], #3} & @@@ 
   id[[#]]) & /@ Range@Length@id, 1];
dat = {#2 Cos[2 Pi #], #2 Sin[2 Pi #], #3} & @@@ cols;
rn = RegionNearest[Point[dat], #] & /@ dat1;
sol = # -> #2 & @@@ Thread@{dat, cols};
img1 = Image[Partition[rn /. sol, ImageDimensions[img][[1]]], ColorSpace -> "HSB"];
```

[image]

However, it is slow. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Use `Nearest` instead of `RegionNearest` and don't construct a NearestFunction for every single iteration - just create one nf once. Also look into ImageApply, and ColorReplace as these are fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a much faster version of your code which gives the same output image:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 200];
cols = {{0.13, 0.45, 0.69}, {0.56, 0.54, 0.98}, {0.04, 0.9, 0.97}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};
fn = {#[[2]] Cos[2. Pi #[[1]]], #[[2]] Sin[2. Pi #[[1]]], #[[3]]} &;
dat1 = Map[fn, ImageData@ColorConvert[img, "HSB"], {2}];
dat = fn /@ cols;
nf = Nearest[dat];
nfdat = Map[First@*nf, dat1, {2}];
sol = Thread[dat -> cols];
img1 = Image[nfdat /. sol, ColorSpace -> "HSB"]
```

Comment: perfect, thank you

Answer (score 6):

There is a built-in posterize effect as an option in ImageEffect:

```
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 200];
pos = ImageEffect[img, {"Posterization", 2}] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

If you need to use a specific set of colors, consider ImageRecolor, for example:

```
ImageRecolor[pos, 
    {ColorsNear[Red, .02] -> Purple, ColorsNear[Yellow, .02] -> Green}]
```